# I want to create a function in c++ to read a file having the file as an argument, but I have problems when I compile the program

Tags: c++, file-handling

This is the function that read the file

```
void read_function(istream& filename, vector< vector<double> >& v)
{
//vector<vector<double> > v;
    if (filename)
    {
        string linea; 
        int i = 0;
        while (getline(filename, linea))
        {
            v.push_back(vector<double>());
            stringstream split(linea);
            double value;
            while (split >> value)
            {
                v.back().push_back(value);
            }           
        }
    }
};
```

The main function

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

if (argc < 2)
{   
    cerr << "input file's name\n"<< endl;
}   

string program_name = argv[0];
ifstream input;
input.open(argv[1]);

vector< vector<double> > array;

for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) 
{             
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].size(); j++) 
        cout << read_function(argv[1], array) << '\t';    
        cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code I get the following errors messages

error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::istream& {aka std::basic_istream&}’ from expression of type ‘const char*’
      cout << read_function(argv[1], array) << '\t';

error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void read_function(std::istream&, std::vector >&)’
 void read_function(istream& filename, vector< vector >& v)

Comment: `read_function()` expects `std::istream` but you passed it `const char*`. What do you want?

Comment: I want to pass the name of the file as an argument. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You could change the parameter type to `const char*`, open the file inside the function.

Comment: `read_function` does not return a value, so `cout << read_function(...` is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please dont take this the wrong way, but the errors you made in your code look like this might be a too difficult task for your level of programming skills.

You make a couple of mistakes:

1. You (kind of) declare `input` in `main` but try to use it in `read_function`
2. the parameters you use in `getline` are incorrect
3. the first parameter of `read_function` is of type `ifstream` not `char*`
4. `getline` is a member function of `ifstream`
5. `read_function` returns nothing, so `cout<<read_function(...)` is incorrect

I would suggest before trying to use more complicated things like `sstream`, `fstream` or `vector` you first try to understand how to call a function, what the parameters and their types are, what an object is and how to access its members.

I corrected your mistakes, the code below only reads in numbers from your input file, no characters. I assumed that was your goal, since you used a `double` vector. Also there are more elegant ways to do this, but I tried to stay as close to your code as possible.

code:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

void read_function(char* filename, vector< vector<double> >& v)
{
    int maxNumberOfCharsPerLine=1000;
    ifstream input;
    input.open(filename);
    if(input.is_open())
    {
        char* inputChar;
        string linea; 
        while (input.getline(inputChar, maxNumberOfCharsPerLine))
        {
            linea=inputChar;
            v.push_back(vector<double>());
            stringstream split(linea);
            double value;
            while (split >> value)
            {
                v.back().push_back(value);
            }           
        }
    }
    input.close();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    if (argc < 2)
    {   
        cerr << "no input file's name\n"<< endl;
    }   

    vector< vector<double> > array;
    read_function((char*)argv[1], array); 

    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) 
    {             
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].size(); j++)  
        {
            cout << array[i][j] <<" ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```